# How to get Special price of product list in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I have created one countdown timer for special price, now i want to hide timer if product does not have any special price so how can i do?Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

Using \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...      
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getSpecialPriceById($id)
{
    //$id = '21'; //Product ID
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    return $product->getSpecialPrice();
}

public function getSpecialPriceBySku($sku)
{   
    //$sku = 'test-21'; //Product Sku
    $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    return $product->getSpecialPrice();
}
```

Now you can get this via

```
$this->getSpecialPriceById($id);
$this->getSpecialPriceBySku($sku);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository class to get the special price of the product

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...      
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    ...
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getSpecialPriceById($productId)
{
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
    return $product->getSpecialPrice();
}
```

Now you can get the special price of product by just passing the product id:

```
$this->getSpecialPriceById($productId);
```